# PHP Facebook FQL Multquery and dealing with foreach and variables

Tags: php, facebook, foreach, facebook-fql

Alright, so I am trying to figure this out. Basically I have everything working well except for adding the cover photos to each of the DIVS. Basically I have 2 queries using FQL, and here is my code.

```
$query = 
   '{"query1":"SELECT aid, cover_pid, name, description FROM album WHERE owner=$fbowner",
     "query2":"SELECT src FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM #query1)"}';

$fqlResult = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
'queries' => $query));          

$fql = $fqlResult[0]['fql_result_set'];
$covers = $fqlResult[1]['fql_result_set'];

$the_count = count($fql);
$i = 0;
foreach($fql as $value) {
 $album_cover = $value['src'];
 echo "<div class='fb_block'>";
 echo "<a href='" . $url . "?action=list_pics&aid=" . $value['aid'] . "&album_name=" . $value['name'] . "'>";
 echo "<img src='{$covers[$i]['src']}' border='1'>";
 echo "</a>";
 echo "<h3>".$value['name']."</h3>";
 echo "<p>".$value['description']."</p>";
 echo "</div>";
 $i++;
}
```

Now that works fine, but what if I put this in the mix, the cover photos are all off unless I make $i = 1.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($fql as $value) {
if($value['name'] != 'Wall Photos'){
 $album_cover = $value['src'];
 echo "<div class='fb_block'>";
 echo "<a href='" . $url . "?action=list_pics&aid=" . $value['aid'] . "&album_name=" . $value['name'] . "'>";
 echo "<img src='{$covers[$i]['src']}' border='1'>";
 echo "</a>";
 echo "<h3>".$value['name']."</h3>";
 echo "<p>".$value['description']."</p>";
 echo "</div>";
 $i++;
}
}
```

and if I stick another foreach in the mix, it grabs all the cover photos and sticks them into each div. So what is the easiest solution to just go in order and grab the cover photo associated with the album node?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, too. You can't rely on the indexes being consistent between these two queries.

To make it work, first modify `query2` to also return `pid`, then replace this line in your code:

```
echo "<img src='{$covers[$i]['src']}' border='1'>";
```

with this:

```
foreach($covers as $cover) {
  if ($value['cover_pid'] === $cover['pid']) {
    echo "<img src='{$cover['src']}' border='1'>";
    break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh.... very good cpilko... Thanks for that suggestion, very good simple logic.. lol

Comment: I appreciate the effort in helping out. You live, you learn, you keep coding! Thanks again!